# Type-Racer, TheWikiGame Multiplayer Game like Website

Tags: php, html, multiplayer

I was wondering how I could make a site that lets people log in and compete against each other. Looking for starting points or any existing frameworks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow. I want to make a Real-Time game where multiple users logged in can play the same game at the same time. I am not working on a game but something that will use a similar system.

Comment: Hello, Udit, I am also trying to work on a game like that but I am not able to come up with the right DB design. Would love to talk about it

Comment: You should use a simple User table and then rely on web-sockets to establish your connections between these users based on their states.

Comment: I am using python and I understand the usage of web sockets. I have an issue in creating multiple games. So that different users can play different games identified by different url's just like in typeracer

Answer (score 1):

you will find many game engines [here](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines). it can be a good starting point to browser through them and find one you feel comfortable with (comfortable with the language for example).

Comment: I am not working on a game. Trying to look for a framework that enables users to log-in in real time and interact with the system.